# Negation of Steinhauss Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Steinhauss theorem states that:
If $A \in \mathscr{M}$ and $m(A)>0$, then {$x-y :x, y\in A$} contains an interval centered at $0$.

I'm trying to show that there exists a non-measurable set, then {$x-y :x, y\in A$} contains no interval.
The only set I can think of that contains no intervals is the Fat Cantor set, but I don't know how to use that here since I need a set that is non-measurable. Any suggestions?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be true. Take any non-measurable set and union it with $[0, 1]$, which is still non-measurable. But clearly the difference set contains an interval centered at 0.  Maybe you need more restrictions?

Comment: @CalvinLin Well, I don't need to prove it for every non-measurable set. Just that there exists one where it is true.

Comment: If so, instead of "if we have ...", phrase it as "there exists a ...".

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you, I made the edit to the original problem